# how do i fixed this "Ports are being used. Please change ports numbers." in samsung all in one security system?

Tags: ports, router, port-forwarding, cctv

I have a samsung all in one security camera system and I had set up my camera system online and it was working perfectly almost a week.

One day i wasn't able to view my camera online so just checked setting in my DVR so it's show me this message "Ports are being used. Please change ports numbers." I have no idea how to do port forwarding do i need to change from the router or the DVR.

If anyone know the solution please let me know. It would be really appreciate for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You may simply have a hung daemon attached the port. You can either kill the old process and try it again or as much as I hate to say this "reboot it if you don't know how to kill the process". I don't know what OS you're using but that's a pretty common error message for a lot of systems

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and I can't restart my router because i'm using into my store so everything will be closed if I restart my router. Is there any other way to fix it problem?
@Trey Blalock

Comment: I'm sure there is another way, there always is, but I think this problem is in the DVR (I have limited info from this post though) since that appears to be where you saw the message (it's a local error message if that helps). Generally you can spawn duplicate processes on other ports so you may be able to "add" the camera again as a new camera on another port too.

Comment: I'm getting this message into DVR and I don't know how to add new camera and there are two options device ports(which I setted up 4520-4524 ) and HTTP port (which I setted up 80) even I don't know because of which port I'm getting this error.
@Trey Blalock

Comment: Can you stop and restart the DVR software ? that alone may also free up the port in use.

Comment: I did but still getting same error message into DVR. @Trey Blalock

Comment: Can you do an lsof -i , or equivalent, on that device to see what's listening on that port. It's possible another piece of software is conflicting with it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this same issue by doing the following:

- Remove registered product from samsungipolis.com
- In Samsung NVR admin panel, update connection tab to these settings: DHCP, TCP, Port 4520 (the default settings seen in the manual)
- Shut down Samsung NVR
- Reboot both cable modem and router
- Turn on Samsung NVR
- Re-register product at samsungipolis.com
- In Samsung NVR admin panel, update DDNS with registered product ID
- Quick Connect was now successful

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP has already stated he doesn't want to reboot his router "I can't restart my router because i'm using into my store so everything will be closed if I restart my router."

Comment: The original question only asks: "how do i fixed this “Ports are being used. Please change ports numbers.” in samsung all in one security system?". I missed his unfortunate circumstance about not being able to restart his router. 


I'm posting a solution that worked for me and if that helps others, so be it.